# Get the caret position (line and char) in an FMX TMemo

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, caret, tmemo

I try to show the position of a memo's caret in a statusbar which contains two labels.

I tried this:

```
lblX.Text := Memo.Caret.Pos.X.ToString();

lblY.Text := Memo.Caret.Pos.Y.ToString();
```

The two values seems to represent the real position from left and top of the memo.

Is it possible to get it as row (lines) and cols (chars)?

I want to clarify that I work with **firemonkey** in order to be able to compile my project towards windows and linux.

Thank you already for your answers.

Selticq.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used FMX before, but using Code Insight I immediately found that `Memo.CaretPosition.Line` and `Memo.CaretPosition.Pos` represent the current line and column, respectively.

This is confirmed by the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Memo.TCustomMemo.CaretPosition):

> `Line` represents the number of the line containing the cursor, indexed from zero.
>
> `Pos` represents the horizontal character coordinate of the cursor, indexed from zero.
>
> [...]
>
> Thus, if `Line = 3` and `Pos = 5`, then the cursor is at the fourth line and at the sixth character from the start of the line.

Comment: :-s, I think i was too tired... Thank you for your rapid response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the memo caret position, you can use code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
begin
    lblX.Text := (Memo1.CaretPosition.Pos + 1).ToString;
    lblY.Text := (Memo1.CaretPosition.Line + 1).ToString;
end;
```

And if you want a complete sample code with that method called at the correct event handlers, here it is:

```
unit FmxMemoCaretPosDemoMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Memo.Types,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    lblX: TLabel;
    lblY: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift:
        TShiftState);
    procedure Memo1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
        TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    procedure UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
    ActiveControl := Memo1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
    Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
    UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateCaretPosDisplay;
begin
    lblX.Text := (Memo1.CaretPosition.Pos + 1).ToString;
    lblY.Text := (Memo1.CaretPosition.Line + 1).ToString;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, and the quality of it.